# How to track certain iPhone device IDs to prevent re-installing

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to figure out a way to track, or document certain device identifiers so that if someone re-installs my app, they have to use their old account. Otherwise, what is happening right now, are people are getting blocked on the app because of improper use, they are then deleting the app, re installing, and are able to make a new account. I am making it stricter with a few ideas, but one of my ideas was to track the device IDs to prevent two users from having the same device ID.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: The only identifier you have is `identifierForVendor`. This can change in some circumstances.

Comment: Will this change when someone deletes and then reinstalls the application?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own identifier and store it in the keychain (together with the other sensitive user details). This is not deleted when the app is deleted, only if the device is restored to a clean install or an old backup before the app was installed.

Comment: I have saved everything to NSUserDefaults. Is this something different? Could you possibly present some code that I could reference?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is just plainly like saving to a file. It is saved in your apps sandbox. It's deleted together with your app

Comment: Find a wrapper you like from GitHub and use it, like https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith